# VIM GTK-UI font

Tags: vim, fonts

The vim manual states:

```
    On systems where 'guifontset' is supported (X11) and 'guifontset' is
not empty, then 'guifont' is not used.

Spaces after a comma are ignored.  To include a comma in a font name
precede it with a backslash.  Setting an option requires an extra
backslash before a space and a backslash.  See also
|option-backslash|.  For example: >
    :set guifont=Screen15,\ 7x13,font\\,with\\,commas
will make Vim try to use the font "Screen15" first, and if it fails it
will try to use "7x13" and then "font,with,commas" instead.
```

So, I would like to do the following:

```
if has("gui_running")
  if has("gui_gtk2")
       set guifont=Droid\ Sans\ Mono,Inconsolata,Monospace
  elseif has("gui_win32")
    set guifont=Droid\ Sans\ Mono:h10,Consolas:h11:cANSI
  endif
endif
```

Trouble is that it does not work for me... I have been trying for a couple of hours on CentOS6.3 and Debian Wheey, but when ever I write this command like this, VIM will just start with Sans font. 
Am I doing something wrong? How do you smartly detect which fonts are on the system ?

Comment: I have this issue too; `set guifont=MissingFont,Monospace` results in using the `Sans` font rather than `Monospace` as instructed.  I also use gui_gtk2 but would also like a GUI-agnostic solution.

Comment: Okay, it looks like a bug in GTK vim.  It probably uses [fontconfig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fontconfig), which _always_ finds a match to a query (test on the command line with e.g. `fc-match MissingFont`), so the second item will never be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I know this is probably not the right way, but it works. So, here is how I set a fallback font for VIM-GTK:

```
if has("gui_running")
   if has("gui_gtk2")
        let dsm=system('fc-list | grep -c Droid\ Sans\ Mono')
        let cons=system('fc-list | grep -c Inconsola')
        if ( dsm > 0)
           set gfn=Droid\ Sans\ Mono\ 10
        elseif ( cons > 0)
           set gfn=Inconsolata\ 12
        else 
           set gfn=Monospace\ 10
        endif
   elseif has("gui_win32")
      set guifont=Droid\ Sans\ Mono:h10,Consolas:h11:cANSI
   endif
endif
```

This snippet will check if `Droid Sans Mono` is installed, and also if `Inconsolata` is installed. 
If the first one is install, the UI font will be `Droid Sans Mono`, if not it will be set to `Inconsolata`, and finally, it will be set to `Monospace`.
On Windows 7 the comma separated list just works.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. The problem here is that when Vim calls `gui_init_font` ([code](https://github.com/vim/vim/blame/071d4279d6ab81b7187b48f3a0fc61e587b6db6c/src/gui.c#L623)) it expects if `gui_mch_get_font` ([code](https://github.com/vim/vim/blame/071d4279d6ab81b7187b48f3a0fc61e587b6db6c/src/gui_gtk_x11.c#L4678)) fails it can move on to the next font in the comma-separated list. But in GTK `gui_mch_get_font` calls `pango_font_description_from_string` ([code](https://github.com/vim/vim/blame/071d4279d6ab81b7187b48f3a0fc61e587b6db6c/src/gui_gtk_x11.c#L4658)) which will never fail, it'll just return a default.

But `pango_font_description_from_string` itself takes a comma-separated list of families followed by style options, size and variations and has its own fallback logic ([doc](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/pango-Fonts.html#pango-font-description-from-string)) withe the following format: `[FAMILY-LIST] [STYLE-OPTIONS] [SIZE] [VARIATIONS]`. Thus escape your list as follows:

```
if has("gui_running")
  if has("gui_gtk2") || has("gui_gtk3")
    set guifont=Droid\ Sans\ Mono\\,Inconsolata\\,Monospace 10
  elseif has("gui_win32")
    set guifont=Droid\ Sans\ Mono:h10,Consolas:h11:cANSI
  endif
endif
```

Then Pango will do the fallback work and pick the right font for you. On GTK it seems to be best to fully escape your string and let GTK do the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I either failed to get [Oz123's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15706027/519360) properly abstracted into a function or else otherwise couldn't get this working on my system.  I had additional issues due to actually using two users (a sandboxed web user and my main account); there was some problem executing `fc-list`).

My workaround was to reassign the alias for the Monospace font, **which affects all of my apps** (don't employ this technique if you only want this to work in gvim).

This change goes into `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf`:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
  <alias>
    <family>monospace</family>
    <prefer><family>Panic Sans</family></prefer>
  </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

I chose [Panic Sans](http://blog.cbowns.com/2007/11/panic-sans-a-monospaced-font/) ([unofficially hosted here](https://github.com/chrissimpkins/codeface/tree/master/fonts/panic-sans)), a variant of the [highly popular](https://www.slant.co/topics/67/viewpoints/4/~best-programming-fonts~dejavu-sans-mono) free [DejaVu Sans Mono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DejaVu_fonts) font, because it is particularly good at rendering code (it additionally solves the underscore and dash problem in DejaVu).  The font's files themselves live in my `~/.fonts/Panic_Sans` directory.

Installing it in this manner allows me to share my `~/.vimrc` between systems and not have to worry about whether Panic Sans is installed on them.

This means that my `~/.vimrc` now merely contains:

```php
if has("gui_running")
  if has("gui_gtk2")
    set guifont=Monospace\ 7
  endif
  " …
```

And this works because the fontconfig alias properly matches Monospace to Panic Sans:

```
$ fc-match Monospace
PanicSans.ttf: "Panic Sans" "Regular"
```